# Is there a way to save and load the vocabulary of a Gensim Doc2Vec model

Tags: python, pyspark, gensim, doc2vec

> edit

The train corpus is a Spark dataframe I built before this step. I load it from parquet format and created a "Feed" class that give to Gensim lib the iterator on the train corpus :

```
class Feed():
    def __init__(self, train_data):
        self.train_data = train_data

    def __iter__(self):
        for row in self.train_data.rdd.toLocalIterator():
            yield \
                gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(\
                words=[kw.lower() for kw in row["keywords"]] + list(row["tokens_filtered"]),\
                tags=[row["id"]])


sdf = spark.read.parquet(save_dirname)
train_corpus = Feed(sdf)
```

> end edit

I wish to train a Gensim Doc2Vec model on ~9 millions news text documents. Here is my model definition :

```
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(
        workers=8,
        vector_size=300,
        min_count=50,
        epochs=10)
```

The first step is getting the vocabulary :

```
model.build_vocab(train_corpus)
```

It ends up in 90 minutes. Here is the logging info at the end of this process :

```
INFO:gensim.models.doc2vec:collected 4202859 word types and 8950263 unique tags from a corpus of 8950339 examples and 1565845381 words
INFO:gensim.models.word2vec:Loading a fresh vocabulary
INFO:gensim.models.word2vec:min_count=50 retains 325027 unique words (7% of original 4202859, drops 3877832)
INFO:gensim.models.word2vec:min_count=50 leaves 1546772183 word corpus (98% of original 1565845381, drops 19073198)
INFO:gensim.models.word2vec:deleting the raw counts dictionary of 4202859 items
INFO:gensim.models.word2vec:sample=0.001 downsamples 9 most-common words
INFO:gensim.models.word2vec:downsampling leaves estimated 1536820314 word corpus (99.4% of prior 1546772183)
INFO:gensim.models.base_any2vec:estimated required memory for 325027 words and 300 dimensions: 13472946500 bytes
```

Then I train the model with an iterator class on the train corpus :

```
model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=nb_rows, epochs=model.epochs)
```

The last training logs are :

```
INFO:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH 1 - PROGRESS: at 99.99% examples, 201921 words/s, in_qsize 16, out_qsize 0
INFO:gensim.models.base_any2vec:worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 7 more threads
INFO:gensim.models.base_any2vec:worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 6 more threads
INFO:gensim.models.base_any2vec:worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 5 more threads
INFO:gensim.models.base_any2vec:worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 4 more threads
```

But it never finish the remaining threads.
It's not the first time I encounter this problem, even with much smaller train corpus. Usually, I relaunch the entire process (vocabulary setting and model training) and it goes on.

By now, to save time, I wish to NOT calculate again the vocabulary, getting in place the previously succesfully calculated one, and only try to train again the model. Is there a way to save the vocab part only of the model, then load it to train the model directly on train corpus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the reason for the hang, it looks like you're generally doing the right things, but something might be going wrong with your `train_corpus`, whose construction you haven't shown.

Double-check its implementation, and perhaps edit your question to show more details of its type/initialization. Review the logs to see if there's evidence any of the threads hit errors that left them in a state where they're not reporting back as required.

You can `.save()` various parts of the `Doc2Vec` model, such as `model.wv.save(wv_path)` – but there's no simple way to reconstruct a model from those sub-parts. (It's possible but requires careful attention to the object's required state, from reviewing the source, and is error prone.)

But also, and more relevant, you can `.save()` the full `Doc2Vec` model at any time – and that's probably a better approach for your needs. That is, you can `.save()` it after `build_vocab()`, or after a call to `.train()`, etc.

If in fact your current hang is in some notebook where you can interrupt the hung action, and execute new code in a new cell, you can probably just save the model from there, debug your `train_corpus`, then re-load & re-train – as long as the corpus size/vocabulary matches what was learned in `build_vocab()`.

**However**, such a partially-trained `.save()` will, at the end, have been influenced by the nearly-complete training that already occurred. So, the end results won't be a true reflection of just your configuration parameters, but also bunch of excess ad-hoc training.

If you want to "clear" the lingering effects of that partial training after re-loading a saved `Doc2Vec` model, I believe the following should do it:

```
model.trainables.reset_weights(model.hs, model.negative, model.wv, model.docvecs)
```

Comment: Hi gojomo, thanks. I'll try to save the model after the vocabulary building and reset the model's weights before training if it fail again. I edited the question to include train corpus building. How to get more logs from gensim in order to explain the hang ?

Comment: ... and I don't understand what could be wrong in the train corpus to produce such a thread hang. Have you some examples in mind ?

Comment: I'd expect watching standard-out/standard-error consoles, plus INFO logging you've already got on, to show any major blocks – you'd just have to comb through all the logs for the entire run. (You could also try setting gensim's log-level to DEBUG, but unsure that'd catch anything else relevant.) I see you're using `spark`, which implies data may be collected from many sources over the network – & could introduce other possible failure modes. So watching spark's logging/log-levels may help. Can you verify outside gensim that `train_corpus` will offer `nb_rows` examples, on repeated iterations?

Comment: As the toLocalIterator() function load each Spark partition in the driver, I increased the Spark driver allocated memory (and decrease the workers ones) and finally it worked.
However, I'm not sure it was the root cause of the threads hanging : the same problem occured with much small dataset (without Spark), and worked fine if I just relaunched the whole training process (including vocabulary).
It would be fine if there was a parameter in the train function that save the intermediary model between each epoch and permit to start again the training at that point in case of failure.

Comment: Anyway, I mark the question answered as your proposition may be a solution. Thanks again.